# Custom sorting Dictionary<string, JToken> traverse down using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I currently have `Dictionary<string, JToken> item` defined as an object class. This is not the root object but is the 2nd level.

```
public class Root
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Table Table {get; set; }

}
public class Table
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> item { get; set; }

}
```

With this I am looking to deserialize and sort incoming json in this class. Currently all json objects are unordered. I am looking to use properties in each object to create order.

Please see JSON structure:

```
 {
        'name': 'Customer Table',
        'Table': {
            'name': {
                'id': 'name',
                'type': 'info'
                'description': 'Customer table info'
            },
            'RowId-123': {
                'id': 'RowId-123',
                'type': 'Row',
                'children': [
                    'ColumnId-367'
                ],
                'index': 1,
                'parentId': 'custom'
            },
            'ColumnId-367': {
                'id': 'ColumnId-367',
                'type': 'Column',
                'children': [],
                'parentId': 'RowId-123'
            },
            'RowId-476': {
                'id': 'RowId-476',
                'type': 'Row'
                'components': [
                    'ColumnId-317',
                    'ColumnId-327'
                ],
                'index': 2,
                'parentId': 'custom'
            },
            'ColumnId-317': {
                'id': 'ColumnId-317',
                'type': 'Column'
                'components': [],
                'index': 0,
                'parentId': 'RowId-476'
            },
            'ColumnId-327': {
                'id': 'ColumnId-327',
                'type': 'Column',
                'components': [],
                'index': 1,
                'parentId': 'RowId-476'
            },
            'TextContent12': {
                'id': 'TextContent12',
                'type': 'Text',
                'index': 0,
                'parentId': 'custom'
            }
        }
    }
```

I have Linq queries below.

```
           //Get all objects that has parent custom top level layer.
            var top = root.Table.item.Values
            .Where(x => x["parentId"].Value<string>() == "custom")
            .OrderBy(i => i["index"]);

            //Only looks at Index 0 and Row type.
            var row = root.Table.item.Values
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x["type"].Value<string>() == "Row" && x["index"].Value<int>() == 0);

            //Get children column of row.
            var column = root.Table.item.Values
            .Where(x => x["parentId"]?.Value<string>() == row["id"].Value<string>())
            .OrderBy(i => i["index"]);
```

I am struggling to combine my linq queries to loop through the index and get my desired output. How can I combine the queries together which will increment index based on max value of Item not within a row or row object to produce the below output.

```
Index 0 Content:
'TextContent12': {
                'id': 'TextContent12',
                'type': 'Text',
                'index': 0,
                'parentId': 'custom'
            }


Index 1 Content:
 'RowId-123': {
                'id': 'RowId-123',
                'type': 'Row',
                'children': [
                    'ColumnId-367'
                ],
                'index': 1,
                'parentId': 'custom'
            },
            'ColumnId-367': {
                'id': 'ColumnId-367',
                'type': 'Column',
                'children': [],
                'parentId': 'RowId-123'
            }

Index 2 Content:

'RowId-476': {
                'id': 'RowId-476',
                'type': 'Row'
                'components': [
                    'ColumnId-317',
                    'ColumnId-327'
                ],
                'index': 2,
                'parentId': 'custom'
            },
            'ColumnId-317': {
                'id': 'ColumnId-317',
                'type': 'Column'
                'components': [],
                'index': 0,
                'parentId': 'RowId-476'
            },
            'ColumnId-327': {
                'id': 'ColumnId-327',
                'type': 'Column',
                'components': [],
                'index': 1,
                'parentId': 'RowId-476'
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to know the max index to loop through the items.  You've already used `OrderBy` to ensure they are in order by index.  So you just need a `foreach` loop at each level.  If you want to know what is the index of the current item within the loop body, you can get it using `item["index"]` as shown below:

I *think* this is what you are looking for:

```
// Get all objects at the top level (parentId is "custom") ordered by index
var top = root.Table.item.Values
    .Where(x => x["parentId"].Value<string>() == "custom")
    .OrderBy(i => i["index"]);

// Loop through top level items 
foreach (JToken item in top)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index " + item["index"] + " Content:");
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());  // output item JSON - could be Row or something else 

    // Check whether the current item is a Row
    if (item["type"].Value<string>() == "Row")
    {
        // If so, get all items which have this row as a parent ordered by index
        var children = root.Table.item.Values
            .Where(x => x["parentId"].Value<string>() == item["id"].Value<string>())
            .OrderBy(i => i["index"]);

        // loop through the child items
        foreach (JToken child in children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child.ToString());  // output child JSON
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rvs675

As an aside, your JSON has some inconsistencies, and I'm not sure whether those are expected or if you are manually editing the JSON and introducing errors as a result (seems likely).  For example:

- `ColumnId-367` does not have an `index` value, whereas all the other items do.  Since we are trying to order by `index`, this raises some questions about what should happen when the index is missing.  If this is a real possibility, you will likely need to make some adjustments to the code to account for this.
- `RowId-123` has a `children` array, whereas `RowId-476` has a `components` array instead.  It doesn't seem to matter for purposes of this question, since we are using `ParentId` to relate the items.  But still it makes me wonder which is correct and whether this will lead to problems later.
- The comma separators are missing from between various properties throughout the JSON, which will prevent it from parsing correctly.

Remember, "[garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)".

Comment: Thanks for this Brian. I made it over complicated and already had the info that I needed in some LINQ queries. Can I ask how I can pass each index as a single object to a method? So in instance this method will see its a type text in index 0 and extract some properties. Do I add them into a list of <JTokens>? I am fairly new to JToken, JObject etc..

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from passing a `JToken` to another method.  Make your method signature accept a `JToken` parameter, e.g. `void MyMethod(JToken item)`. Then inside the method you can extract property values as I showed in the answer above, e.g. `var type = item["type"].Value<string>()`. Another alternative is to create a model class and then use `item.ToObject<YourClass>()` to populate it from the `JToken`. Then you can pass that class to your method instead.  And if you have multiple items to pass, then sure, passing them as a list makes sense (either `JToken` or model class).

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of passing each Index scope to mymethod(JToken item). As I am slightly confused and feel like I will write duplicated code for what I am trying to achieve. I have printed out each object to this method however I would like to pass each index to their associated method e.g. Index 0 is just a text, I would like to pass this method that will wrap it in a Row/Column object. Once done move onto to Index 1 check what object exists. Do I need to write the same linq to select the objects or do i read it linearly?